# How to create valid Avro format file nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery, avro

I'm trying to create a valid avro file for uploading to google-bigquery.

```
var avro = require('node-avro-io').DataFile.AvroFile();
var schema = {
            "name": "data",
            "type": "record",
            "fields": [
                {"name":"key","type": "string"},
                {"name":"value","type": "string"},
                {"name":"flag","type": "boolean"},
                {"name":"subrecord","type":"record","fields":[
                    {"name":"key","type":"string"},
                    {"name":"value","type":["string","int","null"]}
                ]}
            ]
};
var writer = avro.open("myAvroFile.avro", schema, { flags: 'w' , codec: 'deflate'});
writer
    .append({ key:"john", value:"hive", flag: true, subrecord: { key: "preference", value: 2}})
    .append({ key:"eric", value:"lola", flag: true, subrecord: { key: "postcode", value: null}})
    .end({ key:"fred", value:"wonka", flag: false, subrecord: { key: "city", value: "michigan"}});
```

and here is  `myAvroFile.avro`:

```
Obj�avro.codec�deflate�avro.schema�{"name":"data","type":"record","fields":[{"name":"key","type":"string"},{"name":"value","type":"string"},{"name":"flag","type":"boolean"},{"name":"subrecord","type":"record","fields":[{"name":"key","type":"string"},{"name":"value","type":["string","int","null"]}]}]} �3�ä0�x���A� @0O� )�T�%H4��:�*Uy�>P0��%�05k��n�d�T�������\����I�3�ä0�x�
```

but when I try uploading it to big-query it fails:

```
The Apache Avro library failed to parse file
```

when I try uploading the unzipped avro fli from the following link I succeed. `https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/yob1900.avro.zip`

any reason why `myAvroFile.avro` isn't valid?
how do I use `node-avro-io` library to create valid avro files?

Comment: Not sure I can deal with the embedded Avro file. If you could email it to me at huazhang at google.com I can take a look.

Comment: Yes, that's  the problem.. When I remove the nested fields it works well..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like comment has a very small limit. I'll post as an answer.

Here's the error message I got using avro-tools:

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.avro.SchemaParseException: "record" is not a defined name. The type of the "subrecord" field must be a defined name or a {"type": ...} expression.

I've found avro-tools handy for playing with avro files. This [link](http://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2013/03/17/reading-and-writing-avro-files-from-the-command-line/) explains how to use it.

The type field of the "subrecord" filed needs to be a schema. According to the Avro [specification](http://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.1/spec.html#schemas):

> type: A JSON object defining a schema, or a JSON string naming a
>   record definition (required).

So you should change it like this:

```
{"name":"subrecord",
 "type": {"name":"subrecord_type",
          "type":"record",
          "fields":[{"name":"key","type":"string"},
                    {"name":"value","type":["string","int","null"]}
                   ]
         }
}
```